# Handling all possible values for null column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have struggled with this issue for several weeks. I have Googled it and have zero relevant results (which probably means I can't figure out how to Google it - not that the answer isn't out there!)

Assume four tables

Table 1 - templates

```
Template 1...  
Template 2...  
Template 3...  
Template 4...
```

Table 2 - Periods

```
Period 1...  
Period 2...  
Period 3...  
Period 4...
```

Table 3 - Type

```
Type 1...  
Type 2...
```

Table 4 - TemplateMatrix

Contains the matrix for which templates are applicable to which period and type.  Most of the templates are applicable to all periods except 1 and there are specific templates for that period. Rather than create a templateMatrix record for every template for every period, I create one record for each specific period template with that periodID

EX:

```
PeriodID,   TypeID,  TemplateID  
1       ,   1     ,  1
2       ,   1     ,  2
```

and a record with a NULL for PeriodID for all other periods for their templates.

EX:

```
PeriodID,   TypeId, TemplateID  
NULL    ,   1,      3  
NULL    ,   2,      4
```

There are actually about 40 Periods and about 8 Templates and 2 types.

What I need is a view that will give me all possible Template and Period combinations- those that are expressly defined and all others.

In other words,

```
Period 1, Type 1, Template 1  
Period 2, Type 1, Template 2  
Period 3, Type 1, Template 3  
Period 3, Type 2, Template 4  
Period 4, Type 1, Template 3  
Period 4, Type 2, Template 4  
Period 5, Type 1, Template 3  
Period 5, Type 2, Template 4  
Period 6, Type 1, Template 3  
Period 6, Type 2, Template 4
```

Worst case scenario, I could add all possible records to the matrix; however, that doesn't seem very normalized to me since the only difference between the bulk of the records would be the Period ID.

Any ideas? I really am at my wits end.

Thanks,
John

Comment: If your question had provided a script to create and populate tables along with expected results I would have answered it but I can't be bothered setting up these 4 test tables myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've struggled for weeks with a problem that could be solved by simply **storing important business data directly in a table**. We're talking about, at most, around 360 rows, right? Just insert the rows. Jeez.

The root cause of your problem is that a) you're trying to shoehorn two predicates into one table, and b) you're hoping to redefine what NULL means.

```
PeriodID,   TypeID,  TemplateID  
1       ,   1     ,  1
NULL    ,   1     ,  3
```

You want the first row to mean something like this:

> Template [TemplateID] is used in
>   period [PeriodID] for something of
>   type [TypeID]

But you want the second row to mean something like

> Template [TemplateID] is used in every
>   period that hasn't been identified by [PeriodID] in some other row
>   for something of type [TypeID]

Trying stuff like that will almost always lead to grief.

Comment: Thanks so much for your heartfelt response. The ultimate goal in not requiring every row was so that in the future when the users want to add new templates, etc. they would NOT have to add a row for every possible period, (or type, or whatever) when the data was essentially the same.  Believe me, I know that adding the rows will work. I was trying to simplify the process for my users - which is what I thought it was supposed to be about.

Comment: Simplifying the process is a good idea. But simplifying it to the point of breaking your data model is *not* a good idea. If you want to simplify adding templates, types and such, write a stored procedure to do the hard work.

Answer (score 0):

The following select should work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.PeriodID, ty.TypeID, tmpl.TemplateID 
FROM TemplateMatrix AS matrix 
JOIN Periods AS p ON 
   (
       -- Defined Periods
       (matrix.PeriodID = p.PeriodID) OR 
       -- Undefined Periods, excluding defined cases
       (
           IsNull(matrix.PeriodID, p.PeriodID) = p.PeriodID 
           AND p.PeriodID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT defMtrx.PeriodID FROM TemplateMatrix AS defMtrx)
       )
   )
JOIN Type AS ty ON (matrix.TypeID = ty.TypeID) 
JOIN Templates AS tmpl ON (matrix.TemplateID = tmpl.TemplateID)
```

This should only map `NULL` for PeriodID to the values for Period that aren't explicitly defined in your TemplateMatrix table, and use the defined combinations for Period/Type/Template when available.

Comment: The problem with that SELECT is it includes double records for the Defined Period - one for the defined Template and one for the 'un-Defined' template.

Comment: @John: This can be resolved by using `SELECT DISTINCT`.  I've updated the query above.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't fix the issue because TemplateID IS unique for the period.

Comment: @John: I see, looks like I misunderstood what you were after. As Catcall mentions, this is not what `NULL` is really intended for. However, I believe my most recent edit should address this scenario for you.

Comment: thanks for your post. I ended up doing what catcall suggested. The actual application has other predicates that I omitted in the interest of simplifying my question and those predicates would make the query even more complex and unworkable. Thanks for everyone's help and suggestions.